# 'Amazon.Runtime.Internal.FallbackInternalConfigurationFactory' threw an exception

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, asp.net-core-3.1, knox-amazon-s3-client

```
 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(new BasicAWSCredentials(apcong.Value.AWSACCESSKEY, apcong.Value.AWSSECRETKEY), RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
```

not working with .net core 3.1

I have tried to create AmazonS3Client but it is always null and throwing FallbackInternalConfigurationFactory exception

```
        "InnerException": {
        "ClassName": "System.TypeInitializationException",
        "Message": "The type initializer for 'Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Settings.PersistenceManager' threw an exception.",
        "Data": null,
        "HelpURL": null,
        "StackTraceString": "   at Amazon.Util.Internal.SettingsManager.GetSettings()\r\n   at Amazon.Util.Internal.SettingsManager.TryGetObjectByProperty(String propertyName, String value, String& uniqueKey, Dictionary`2& properties)\r\n   at Amazon.Runtime.CredentialManagement.NetSDKCredentialsFile.TryGetProfile(String profileName, CredentialProfile& profile)\r\n   at Amazon.Runtime.CredentialManagement.CredentialProfileStoreChain.TryGetProfile(String profileName, CredentialProfile& profile)\r\n   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ProfileInternalConfiguration.Setup(ICredentialProfileSource source, String profileName)\r\n   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.FallbackInternalConfigurationFactory.Reset()\r\n   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.FallbackInternalConfigurationFactory..cctor()",
        "RemoteStackTraceString": null,

        "TypeName": "Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Settings.PersistenceManager"
    },
    "HelpURL": null,
    "StackTraceString": "   at Amazon.Runtime.ClientConfig.get_RetryMode()\r\n   at Amazon.Runtime.AmazonServiceClient.BuildRuntimePipeline()\r\n   at WebApp.Controllers.SpeakerDiarizationController.ProcessAudioByTrnscribeJob(GeneralObj obj) in SpeakerDiarizationController.cs:line 58",

    "TypeName": "Amazon.Runtime.Internal.FallbackInternalConfigurationFactory"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AWSSDK.S3 3.3.104 worked for me update your all awssdk references to same version 
if you skip any one to downgrade things will be same